# What does cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB do?

Tags: opencv, imshow

I happened to encounter this API cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB. I found it strange because there should have no way to convert an grey scale image to RGB image. So I tried something like this:
I took an image like this:

[image]

The image is shown by plt.imshow(img) (with default arguments).
Then I convert it into grey scale with cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) and get this:

[image]

I know it does not appear grey-scale looking is because  imshow() by default is not displaying grey-scale image (more like heat-map I think). So I used cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) and got this:

[image]

It appears grey to out eyes despite it has three channels now. So I conclude that cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB is a walk-around to display grey-scale image in grey-scale fashion without changing the settings for imshow().

Now my question is, when I use cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) again to convert this three-channel gray image back to one channel, the pixel value is exactly the same as the first time I converted the original image into one channel with cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY):
[image]

In other words, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY can do a many-to-one mapping. I wonder how is that possible.

Comment: Are you using ply.imshow with different cmap on gray image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COLOR_BGR2GRAY` color mode estimates a gray value for each pixel using a weighted sum of `B`, `G`, `R` channels, `w_R*R+w_G*G+w_B*B=Y` per pixel. So any 3 channel image becomes 1 channel.

`COLOR_GRAY2BGR` color mode basically replaces all `B`, `G`, `R` channels with the gray value `Y`, so `B=Y, G=Y, R=Y`. It converts a single channel image to multichannel by replicating.

More documentation about color modes are [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_gray).